How to use Php if statement when shortcode returns empty in WP
For all my AFC fields I'm using a php if statement so that if the field is empty, the entire section containing the field data won't be loaded, for example:
                <?php if( get_field('client_intro') ): ?>
                <section id="client-intro">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <p><?php echo get_field('client_intro'); ?></p> 
                    </div>      
                </section>
                <?php endif; ?>

I wanted to do the same thing with a section that contains shortcode data but I can't figure out what to use. The shortcode is used by a plugin that displays posts, so I tried this (and many others):
             <?php if( have_posts() ): ?>   
             <section id="client-posts">
                 <div class="wrapper">
                 <?php echo do_shortcode('[display-posts posts_per_page="10"]'); ?>
                 </div> 
             </section>
             <?php endif; ?>

Nothing works, the section still loads even without posts. Simply speaking I only want the #client-posts section to load if there are posts, if no posts, don't load.

You can replace your code with the following code
<?php
if ( shortcode_exists( 'display-posts' ) ) {
 $dposts = do_shortcode('[display-posts posts_per_page="10"]');
 if( $dposts !== ''){   
 ?>
 <section id="client-posts">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $dposts; ?>
    </div> 
 </section>
 <?php
 }
}   
?>


Thanks! Fascinating code there. I never would've thought of defining it first. Worked like a charm!
